# How to measure upload/ download speed with Apache FTPClient

Tags: java, android, ftp

I am using Apache FTPClient to download / upload files between android device and some FTP server.
I would like to measure the download and upload speeds in Mbps / KBps.

for upload, my code looks something like this:

```
// myFile is a path for local file inside my android device.
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(myFile);
OutputStream outputStream = ftpclient.storeFileStream(remoteFile);

byte[] bytesIn = new byte[4096];
int read = 0;

while((read = inputStream.read(bytesIn)) != -1) {
    outputStream.write(bytesIn, 0, read);
}

inputStream.close();
outputStream.close();
```

It is important for me to know two things:

1. For download, what I did was to sum up the bytes that I have been read inside the while loop (using inputStream.read(serverFile) return value)
   is it ok ? will it reflect the download speed?
2. For upload, how do I measure correctly the upload speed for a file ? how can it be done by this FTP client ?
   for what I know, outputStream.write() doesn't return useful value..
   my thought is to check after every iteration (writing) what is the updated size of the file in the FTP server but I don't know if this is the right / simplest way. and also, how to implement it with this FTP client.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple solution but is not 100% accurate, you can improve it by adding more sampling rate. For now I just use one sample, (**TotalFileSize**-**CurrentByteTransferred**/(**CurrentTime**-**StartTime**)). You can add more sampling to improve the result. Below are code examples:

*Update upload stats here*

```
private final UploadStats uploadStats = new UploadStats();

private void updateUploadStats(long totalBytesTransferred, int bytesTransferred, long streamSize) {
    long current = System.currentTimeMillis();

    synchronized (this.uploadStats) {
        long timeTaken = (current - uploadStats.getStartTime());

        if (timeTaken > 1000L) {
            uploadStats.setLastUpdated(current);
            uploadStats.setEstimatedSpeed(totalBytesTransferred / (timeTaken/1000L));
        }

        uploadStats.setTotalBytesTransferred(totalBytesTransferred);
        uploadStats.setBytesTransferred(bytesTransferred);
        uploadStats.setStreamSize(streamSize);
    }
}
```

*Create CopyStreamListener and append to FTPClient*

```
        CopyStreamAdapter copyStreamAdapter = new CopyStreamAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void bytesTransferred(long totalBytesTransferred, int bytesTransferred, long streamSize) {
                updateUploadStats(totalBytesTransferred, bytesTransferred, streamSize);
            }
        };

        FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
        ftpClient.connect(url);

        if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(ftpClient.getReplyCode())) {
            ftpClient.disconnect();
            throw new Exception("Unable to connect.");
        }

        if (!ftpClient.login(username, password)) {
            ftpClient.disconnect();
            throw new Exception("Failed to login.");
        }
        ftpClient.setCopyStreamListener(copyStreamListener);
        ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        ftpClient.storeFile(targetPath, inputFile);
        ftpClient.logout();
        ftpClient.disconnect();
```

*Upload Stats bean without getter/setter. Some are irrelevant, can be skipped*

```
public class UploadStats {
private long totalBytesTransferred;
private int bytesTransferred;
private long streamSize;
private long lastUpdated;
private double estimatedSpeed;
private long startTime;
private long totalSize; }
```

This is just a pseudo code. You can improve with threading if you intend to read and display the progress, hence the **syncronized** keyword.